# Dynamic properties passed as C# method parameters

Tags: c#, dynamic-typing

In this code, we pass a property of a dynamic object. For the sake of argument we know the property exists and there isn't a bonehead error like bad casing of the property name.

When we use the property directly in the method invocation, a null is received by the method.
Yet when we assign a local variable from the property, and pass that, the value is received.

```cs
[HttpPost, Route("/not/important")]
public IActionsResult SomeWebApi([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
  HelperMethod(data.fooProperty); // fails
  string fooProp = data.fooProperty;
  HelperMethod(fooProp); // works
}
void HelperMethod(string foo) {
  // use foo
}
```

I have noticed also that constructing an object works. Assume properties are A,B,C:

```cs
var bar = new { data.A, data.B, data.C };
```

This successfully resolves the property values into a strongly but anonymously typed object.

Is the problem with direct use of properties of dynamic objects as method invocation parameters a language bug or is there documentation pertaining to the behaviour of dynamic objects that covers this?

Comment: Is this .net core?

Comment: Do you have any overloads of the `HelperMethod` method? Do you get this problem only for WebAPI methods? It works in a normal console application, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/3P5Nd1. Can you add several logging lines (or `Console.WriteLine`/`Debug.WriteLine()` calls) in your method to check the values at each step and add them to the question (including the changed code with the logging lines)?

Comment: Is it dotnet core? Yes. Is it _strictly_ dotnet core? Good question. I will investigate and extend the question.

Comment: We're doing a release. I hope to return to this problem.